# Razorpay payment button connection in django

Tags: python, django, razorpay

Hey I'm trying to make donation web app in django I have never work in gateway application.

views.py

```
def payment_page(request):
    form = PaymentForm(request.POST or None)
    donation = request.POST.get('donation')
        try:
          donation = int(donation) * 100  # Note 1 Rs == 100 ps
          donation = str(donation)
        except TypeError: 
                donation = 100     
        #   If delete this you will TypeError Razorpay money should be greater than 1 ps 
    return render(request, 'mysite/payment_page.html', {'form':form, 'donation':donation})
```

What I done in try block? 
1 rs is equal to 100ps so I multiple it with 100. If I don't use the try it give me typeError

payment_page.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Donate</button>
        </form>     
    </div>
</div>


<form action="/purchase" method="POST">

     <!-- Note that the amount is in paise = 50 INR -->

<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="rzp_test_VKwzQnRYkTmxEW"
    data-amount="{{ donation }}"
    data-buttontext="Pay"
    data-name="Merchant Name"
    data-description="Purchase Description"
    data-image=""
    data-prefill.email=" email "
    data-theme.color="blue"
></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

How it working right now I enter name, donation amount, email in form click donate the amount it save in database and after that I press pay it display the amount, but I want only one button which can do the both work at the same time or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use "{{ donation }}" it is String by type do {{ donation }} so it will be of type Integer

Comment: doing "{{ donation }}" make it string? when I pass donation data and try to print its type(in views) it prints <class 'str'> that means forms pass data in the form of string right? correct me if I'm wrong forms.py-->> donation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

Comment: Django template will be parsed at server side before sending response to browser your payment gateway implementation is in javascript so in js statement discount="100" Is of type string where discount=100 is integer

Comment: Ok I try the amount={{ donation }} it works! But this is not what I want. It use two button to show(pay) and save(donate) can I make or link pay button with donate button, so when I press donate button it save data and display it

Answer (score 0):

*I know i'm too late but will help someone*
Razorpay's script tag by default will include a button we cant remove that but can be modified by css for `.razorpay-payment-button`